# cacheing with boost optional

Tags: c++, boost

I want to create a cached result in an otherwise non-mutable class like so:

```
class Rot3() {

mutable boost::optional<Matrix3> transpose_;

Rot3 inverse() const {...}
Matrix3 matrix() const {...}

const Matrix3& transpose() const {
  if (!transpose_)
    transpose_.reset(inverse().matrix());
  return *transpose_;
}

};
```

It is concise and seems to work. Is this good practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: `optional` is my first choice when I have to implement a simple cached result and never had any issues with it. In your case it might be wiser to optimize for storage though and let the client of your class perform the caching (if desired).

Comment: If you wanted true caching (not per-instance), look at using something like eBoost Flyweight (does reference counted expiration and many other things, like unique identification straegies) or e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/124053/85371

Comment: Thanks. I found out that another issue with the above scheme is that when a copy is made before transpose is called once, the empty optional is copied. So, making 10 copies and calling transpose on all of them does not save anything.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that since C++11 introduced concurrency semantics to the C++ memory & execution model, the `const` qualifier on member funtions gained an extra meaning: *thread-safe.* That is, it should be possible to call `const` functions on an object concurrently. In fact, if you use your objects with the standard library, it *must* be so (it's one of the prerequisites for interacting with the standard library).

So, to answer your question: there is nothing inherently wrong with it. But to make your class usable with the standard library, you should actually synchronise the access to `transpose_` (or any other mutable members).

It is us to you to decide whether the performance impact of the synchronisation outweighs the gain of caching. As with any other optimisation, a question of "Should I do it?" is best answered by "What does profiling suggest?"

Answer (score 0):

> Is this good practice?

Yes, unless you don't actually need it. This is an optimization, so you may not need caching at all (i.e. if you don't call `transpose()` often, or at most once per instance).

> Is there a better way?

Can't think of anything more simple/idiomatic.